# How to return IList<T>

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3

following function return List of records

```
 public IList<T> GetAll()
 {
   return db.TabMasters.ToList<T>();
 }
```

**Error:** 
*'System.Data.Objects.ObjectSet' does not contain a definition for 'ToList' and the best extension method overload 'System.Linq.Enumerable.ToList(System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable)' has some invalid arguments*

Comment: TabMaster doesn't know the Method ToList so you cant use it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`IList<T>` is the [Interface](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173156.aspx) that is used by `List<T>` and several other similar containers.  You can't return an Interface itself - you have to return an object that implements `IList<T>`.  Though I don't know exactly what your situation is, the best choice is most likely `List<T>`.

Also, you have a problem with the generic Type `T`.  If you want the method to be generic, then you have to cast all the values in `db.TabMasters` to Type T.  This gets tricky because you'll have to limit the possible Types used for T to prevent Exceptions caused by an invalid cast (see [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/d5x73970%28v=vs.80%29.aspx)).  If you only need to return one type, then you should define that as the return type instead of using `T`.  For example, lets say that all the values in `db.TabMasters` are `string`.  Then you'd use:

```
public IList<string> GetAll()
{
    return db.TabMasters.ToList();
}
```

If you really need the method to be generic, then you have to cast the values in db.TabMasters to the type you want to return:

```
public IList<T> GetAll<T>()
{
    return db.TabMasters.Cast<T>().ToList();
}
```

Note that if the object type stored in `db.TabMasters` can't be cast to `T`, the method will throw an `InvalidCastException`.

Happy Coding!

Answer (score 2):

I imagine `TabMasters` is a strongly typed collection and therefore cannot return a list of a generic type. Have you tried `db.TabMasters.ToList()` instead?

Comment: actually the function is as follows: `public IList<T> GetAll()
        {
            return this.ObjectSet.ToList<T>();
        }` instead of that i have to just test performance with direct Database or Repository patter. After then i will remove temporary line.

Answer (score 2):

The correct syntax is:

## `db.TabMasters.Cast<T>().ToList()`

**Documentation:**

- [`IEnumerable<TResult> Enumerable.Cast<TResult>(this IEnumerable source)`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb341406.aspx)
- [`List<TSource> Enumerable.ToList<TSource>(this IEnumerable<TSource> source)`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb342261.aspx)

If you don't want to use the LINQ extension, [`List<T>` has a public constructor that accepts a single `IEnumerable<T>` argument](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/fkbw11z0.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

have you looked here http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd412719.aspx

there appears to be a couple of methods that may be of use AsEnumerable and GetList seem like possibilities